# Single leading underscore in Python function keyword argument

Tags: python, arguments

As a matter of style, is there a reason to or not to use a single-leading-underscore before a keyword argument in a function or method? The only reason I can find or think of is that it's simply not necessary.

Specifically, I'm using this inside a class property, so the setter method can be called with the extra keyword if specifically necessary, but is usually hidden behind a property.

The best answer I could find was a comment on [Single leading underscore before variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52519303/single-leading-underscore-before-variable-name):
"There is absolutely no reason to prefix local variables with anything... It won't cause any issue of course... but it will only makes [sic] anyone reading this code wonder why..."

```py
@property
def my_write(self, message, _hard_set=False):
    if _hard_set: self.eeprom_write(message)
    else: self.ram_write(message)
```

The interpreter doesn't seem to care. Pylint doesn't warn for such use. I'm thinking of a situation where I want to hint an argument is available but not suggested for external use.

Comment: You can't pass arguments to properties anyway so this question is a little confusing.

Comment: Using a boolean argument to modify how a function or method behaves is an anti-pattern.

Comment: It can be used to indicate that an argument is not used in the function, but the parameter is needed for some reason (most likely to make the function compatible with some other interface).

Comment: The pep8 definition for attributes starting with an underscore is `_single_leading_underscore: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. from M import * does not import objects whose names start with an underscore.`. Therefore a leading underscore would imply that this is an attribute that is only accessed within the class / model.

Comment: It is also worth noting that generally properties don't take inputs as functions, for example with the `@property` decorator I would expect the attribute to be `def my_write(self)` which you call `class_name.my_write` or you don't have the decorator and you have an input like `def my_write(self, message)` which you access via `class_name.my_write(message='message')`. With both the decorator and `message` I would expect the error `TypeError: my_write() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'`

Comment: @chepner I am confused. 

so if you have a function `set_cookie(name, value, is_session_cookie=False)`
where session cookies are written to RAM (ram_write) or otherwise to a file (eeprom_write), then you would say this is an anti pattern?

I mean the code  in the question  is a little bizarre (function decorated as @Property)  but having bools changing the behavior of methods is something I see often so perhaps I don't understand your concern

Comment: Yes; you can pass a much more descriptive argument (like `"ram"` or `"eprom"`) to indicate what the function should do, or simply define two different functions `write_ram` and `write_eeprom` to be explicit about what should be done (those two function could wrap a single private parameterized function to do the actual work, which -- maybe -- takes a boolean argument, but the *user* shouldn't have remember what `True` means).

Comment: I suppose I'm trying to be clever instead of clear. Having to ask this question at all probably violates the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: @Maddo: we're talking about function parameters and not class/instance attributes. The meaning of underscore in the latter is straightforward, not so much with the former. Function parameters are public by definition so what indicating that they are actually 'private' would even mean? And yet, Python standard library uses this convention in many places. E.g. look at signature of `random.randrange`